# Como configurar ruta relatativa d eun properties dentro de mi proyecto?

Tags: java, eclipse, archivo-de-propiedades, filereader

estoy intentando agregar la ruta relativa de la siguinte forma pero me arroja FileNotFoundException.Lo intente con ./ y tampoco me funciona,
les agredecería si saben como solucionarlo.

```
public static String obtenerpropiedad(String propiedad) {
    Properties prop = new Properties();
    FileReader leerArchivo = null;
    try {
        leerArchivo = new FileReader("/MotorReglasEM/MotorRegalasEM/MotorReglas-api/src/main/resources/MotorReglas.properties");
        prop.load(leerArchivo);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        logger.error("error cargando archivo de propiedades" + e);

    }
    return prop.getProperty(propiedad);
}
```

Comment: Hola, si lo intenté, es de extención .properties pero así tampoco funciona.

Comment: Disculpa que no te diera una respuesta en concreto. Acá te envío algunos ejemplos de cómo agregar un ruta relativa en FileReader. Son ejemplos que pueden ser perfectamente adaptables a tu pregunta . [https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/384562/165037]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

uso la siguiente forma

```
CodeSource codeSource = Main.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource(); //CodeSource de la clase Main del programa
File archivoJar = new File(codeSource.getLocation().toURI().getPath()); //Archivo jar de la clase Main
String pathArchivoJar =  archivoJar.getParentFile().getPath(); //Path del archivo jar
Properties properties = new Properties();
FileReader fr = new FileReader(pathArchivoJar + "\\carpeta0\\carpeta1\\archivo.properties"); 
properties.load(fr);
```

Esto funciona si la carpeta0 se encuentra en la misma carpeta del archivoJar

Answer (score 0):

Este es el directorio de mi proyecto (El proyecto se llama Directorio_de_trabajo):
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estos son algunos ejemplos de rutas relativas al archivo *java.properties*:

1. Ruta relativa desde Stackoverflow.java:

```
FileReader fr=new FileReader("src/main/otro1/otro/java.properties");
```

2. Ruta relativa desde Stackoverflow1.java:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("main/otro1/otro/java.properties");
```

3. Ruta relativa desde Stackoverflow3.java:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("../src/main/otro1/otro/java.properties");
```

4. Ruta relativa desde Stackoverflow4.java:

```
FileReader fr = new FileReader("../../src/main/otro1/otro/java.properties");
```

Para comprobar que funciona al full, probé imprimir la primera línea del archivo con este código:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{
    FileReader fr=new FileReader("src/main/otro1/otro/java.properties");
    try  {
        BufferedReader r = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = r.readLine();
    if (line != null) {
        System.out.println(line);
    } else {
        throw new IOException("El archivo está vacío: " + fr);
    }
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        throw new IOException("No se puede leer el archivo: " + fr, ex);
    }
}
```

El contenido del archivo *java.properties* es este:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El resultado de la ejecución de este último código, en cada de las clases fue el mismo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]